# Wordpress Plugin print image from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm developing a new plugin. I created a new table in the database.

Now I can save an image in type medium blob, but I can't recover to put in the website, only appear binary code.

How I can codificate this binary code to appear the image??

This is the code to save the image.

```
$tipo = $_FILES['vehiculo_inserta_imagen']['type'];
$tamanio = $_FILES['vehiculo_inserta_imagen']['size'];
$imagen_temporal  = $_FILES['vehiculo_inserta_imagen']['tmp_name'];
//leer el archivo temporal en binario
$fp     = fopen($imagen_temporal, 'r+b');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($imagen_temporal));
fclose($fp);        
//escapar los caracteres
$data = mysql_escape_string($data);
```

And I try to recover using this code:

```
$usuario = esc_attr($current_user->user_login);
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "vehiculos";

$vehiculo= $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name where matricula = '$usuario'; " );
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using an escape function on binary data, it may corrupt the image. How are you doing the insert to the database? What do you do with it after the `$wpdb->get_row()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi maybe you have a error on you code 
please try this and check your code

for upload image

```
<?php
if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db ("phppot_examples");
$imgData =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
$imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO output_images(imageType ,imageData)
VALUES('{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}')";
$current_id = mysql_query($sql) or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Image Insert<br/>" . mysql_error());
if(isset($current_id)) {
header("Location: listImages.php");
}}}
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Upload Image to MySQL BLOB</TITLE>
<link href="imageStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name="frmImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" class="frmImageUpload">
<label>Upload Image File:</label><br/>
<input name="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" />
</form>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and for show the image save on database

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("phppot_examples") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_GET['image_id'])) {
$sql = "SELECT imageType,imageData FROM output_images WHERE imageId=" . $_GET['image_id'];
$result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Retrieving Image BLOB<br/>" . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-type: " . $row["imageType"]);
echo $row["imageData"];
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

for list imagens

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("phppot_examples");
$sql = "SELECT imageId FROM output_images ORDER BY imageId DESC"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>List BLOB Images</TITLE>
<link href="imageStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<img src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["imageId"]; ?>" /><br/>
<?php       
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

For displaying BLOB images to the browser, we have to create a PHP file to do to following.

get image data and type from MySQL BLOB
Set the content-type as image (image/jpg, image/gif, …) using PHP header().
print image content.

good luck and try